# Return "Name"s with value "IE" only if the "Version" is >= 8.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sorry for the terrible wording in the question, struggling to explain this properly.

I have a table like this:

```
Id  Name    Version
1   Chrome  38.0
2   Chrome  36.0
3   Chrome  37.0
4   Firefox 31.0
5   IE      11.0
6   IE      8.0
7   IE      7.0
```

I need a query to return "Name"s with value "IE" only if the "Version" is >= 8.0
Otherwise don't return a version, I would expect the result to be...

```
Id  Name    Version
1   Chrome  null
2   Chrome  null
3   Chrome  null
4   Firefox null
5   IE      11.0
6   IE      8.0
```

If it helps here is my stored procedure so far, this returns all versions which isn't what I want.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCommonBrowserCount]
    @StartDate datetime = NULL,
    @EndDate datetime = NULL,
    @Domain varchar(255) = NULL

    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        [Name],
        COUNT(Name) AS [Count],
        [Version]
    FROM 
        dbo.GetCommonBrowserAccessEvents
    WHERE
        (
            @StartDate IS NULL OR [Date] > @StartDate
        )
        AND
        (
            @EndDate IS NULL OR [Date] < @EndDate
        )
        AND
        (
            @Domain IS NULL OR DomainName = @Domain
        )
    GROUP BY Name,
            [Version]
END
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is just my preference. I default my date parameters to min and max values rather than NULL. (i.e.: `@StartDate = '1/1/1900'` and `@EndDate = '12/31/2050'`) This allows an easier to read WHERE clause.  (i.e.: `WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND ...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case`

```
select id, 
       name,
       case when name = 'IE' 
            then version
            else null
       end as version
from GetCommonBrowserAccessEvents
where not 
(
   name = 'IE' and cast(substring(version, 1, charindex('.', version) - 1) as int) < 8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the result set is just a matter of adding another `AND` to your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND
(
    [Name] <> 'IE' OR [Version] > 8
)
```

In terms of returning `NULL` for `[version]` when it's not IE (why?), you can use `CASE` for that:

```
SELECT
-- ...
CASE WHEN [Name] = 'IE' THEN [Version] ELSE NULL END AS Version
```

(If you were on SQL Server 2012 or higher, you could use [`IIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213574.aspx) instead to be a bit more concise, but not on 2008.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    [Name],
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            [Name] = "IE" AND [Version] >= 8 
        THEN 
            [Version] 
        ELSE 
            NULL 
    END AS [Version]
FROM 
    dbo.GetCommonBrowserAccessEvents
WHERE
    Name != "IE"
    OR
    (Name = "IE" AND Version >= 8)
```